# Encrypting with PBEWITHSHAAND3-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC using phpseclib

Tags: php, security, encryption, phpseclib

I have to encrypt some data to send it to a third party service with PBEWITHSHAAND3-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC.

**I have this working example Java code, provided by the third party:**

```
String algorithm = "PBEWITHSHAAND3-KEYTRIPLEDES-CBC";
String password = "eKhfdPKO54OddrfgghuBGHsA5BGTYHon";
byte[] salt = {-87, -101, -56, 50, 86, 52, -29, 3};
int iterations = 19;

String text = "foobar";

Provider bouncy = new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider();
Security.addProvider(bouncy);

KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, iterations);
SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm, bouncy).generateSecret(keySpec);

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm, bouncy);
cipher.init(1, key, new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterations));

System.out.println(new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes("UTF8")))));
// Output: kaxAiR1Qb9s=
```

**This is my (not working) PHP code using `phpseclib`:**

```
$hash = 'sha1';
$kdf = 'pkcs12';
$password = 'eKhfdPKO54OddrfgghuBGHsA5BGTYHon';
$salt = chr(-87) . chr(-101) . chr(-56) . chr(50) . chr(86) . chr(52) . chr(-29) . chr(3);
$iterations = 19;

$text = "foobar";

$cipher = new \phpseclib\Crypt\TripleDES('cbc');
$cipher->setPassword($password, $kdf, $hash, $salt, $iterations);

echo base64_encode($cipher->encrypt($text));
// Output: daAlVF+JjNg=
```

**Question:** How do I make my PHP code produce the same output as the Java one?

Comment: Why do you think you can just translate Java into PHP?

Comment: There's a lot of errors in your code :-\

Comment: I'm no trying to translate java into PHP, I'm just trying to encrypt stuff in PHP; Java code was provided by third party as reference. Both codes are working, they only misses the imports and includes.

Comment: If they are working, what you want help with?

Comment: Ther are "Working" because they both compile & run. The problem is that PHP code is not producing the same result as Java one...

Comment: Perhaps this example can help you? https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/phpseclib%255CCrypt%255CDES/-/php-phpseclib%255ccrypt%255cdes-class-examples.html

Comment: what does it actually give you as a result?

Comment: By the way, compile and run, does not mean it works :-)

Comment: I typed it in the last line of both codes as a comment...

Comment: Working does **not** mean that code compiles and runs, working means that the correct result is obtained.

Comment: I got a different result using your PHP version "3IrwqunYVxY="

Comment: I got the same result in the Java, so there's something wrong in the PHP version

Comment: Here is the Java version http://jdoodle.com/a/ib4

Comment: Here is the PHP version http://jdoodle.com/a/iaY it's a lot of code in this one, because i had to add the library code in it, so just go down to the end :-)

Comment: I said it was woking in response to Zorkind comment saying there were a lot of errors.
PHP versión should output the same value as the Java one: "kaxAiR1Qb9s=", that's the question, but I don't know how to achieve it.

Comment: Ok i got my PHP version to give the same result as yours, i was using DES and not TripleDES :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found a solution!

I've extracted generated key and IV bytes from Java version:

```
byte[] keyBytes = key.getEncoded();
byte[] iv = cipher.getIV();
```

And used it directly in PHP:

```
$key = chr(208) . chr(193) . chr(208) . chr(49) . chr(81) . chr(84) . chr(244) . chr(181) . chr(234) . chr(244) . chr(94) . chr(164) . chr(44) . chr(55) . chr(244) . chr(64) . chr(233) . chr(97) . chr(4) . chr(64) . chr(179) . chr(155) . chr(161) . chr(155);
$iv = chr(187) . chr(159) . chr(143) . chr(131) . chr(24) . chr(115) . chr(157) . chr(64);

$text = "foobar";

echo openssl_encrypt($text, 'DES-EDE3-CBC', $key, 0, $iv);
// Output: kaxAiR1Qb9s=
```

You can even encode key and IV into base64 so they can be easily written on a config file:

```
$key = base64_decode('0MHQMVFU9LXq9F6kLDf0QOlhBECzm6Gb');
$iv = base64_decode('u5+PgxhznUA=');
```

Thanks all!